# does PIC 16f877a external interrupt can affect all port?

Tags: microcontroller, mikroc

[the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jneec.png)I was working with PIC 16f877a and LCD, I want to powering a motor with transistor that used for relay with 9v battery and my LCD become error, does this because external interrupt?, because i used the external interrupt for a button on other port

I already change the program but its doesn't working and my LCD always display random character when the transistor is switching with 9v battery

```
int SetMoist=85;
int SetMoistR=0;
int SetMoistL=0;
int cset=0;
int sensingCounter=0;
int screenCounter=0;
int getMoist=0;
char *buffer = "00";
int turnON=1;

#define LCD_ON lcd_cmd(_LCD_TURN_ON);
#define LCD_OFF lcd_cmd(_LCD_TURN_OFF);

//LCD
sbit LCD_RS at RC1_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RC2_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RC3_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RC4_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RC6_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISC1_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISC2_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISC3_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISC4_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISC6_bit;
//End of LCD

void interrupt() {

//Hardware interrupt flag
                     if(INTCON.b0 ==1){
                                    turnON=1;
                                    if(portb.b7==1){
                                                    if(SetMoist==99)
                                                    {}
                                                    else{
                                                    SetMoist++;
                                                    cset=0;
                                                           }
                                                    }

                                    if(portb.b6==1){
                                                    turnON=1;
                                                    if(SetMoist==5)
                                                    {}
                                                    else{
                                                         SetMoist--;
                                                         cset=0;
                                                         }
                                                    }

                                     if(portb.b5==1){
                                                     turnON=1;
                                                     portc.b0 =!portc.b0;
                                                     }
                                     intcon.b0=0;
                                     }
                     if(portb.b4==1){
                                     turnON=1;
                                     }
//End of Hardware interrupt flag
// Timer0 flag
                     if(INTCON.b2 ==1){
                                       sensingCounter++;
                                       screenCounter++;

//2 minutes timer for moisture
                                       if(sensingCounter==50){
                                                              sensingCounter=0;
                                                              getMoist=ADC_Read(0);
                                                              getMoist=(getMoist/1024.0)*100.0;
                                                              if(getMoist>setMoist){
                                                                                    portc.b0=0b1;
                                                                                    }
                                                              else if(getMoist<setMoist){
                                                                                         portc.b0=0b0;
                                                                                         }
                                                              } //end moisture

                                        if(screenCounter==1000){
                                                                screenCounter=0;
                                                                turnON=0;
                                                                }

                                        intcon.b2=0;
                                        }
//End of timer0 flag
//interrupt
                }

void main() {
            INTCON = 0b10101000;
 //Timer0
            option_reg= 0b10000111;
  //TMR0=0;
 //End of timer0
             trisb= 0b11111111;
             trisd = 0b00000000;
             trisc.b7 =0;
             trisc.b0=0;
             portc.b0=0;
             portd.b7=1;
             portc.b7= 1;
             trisa=0xff;
             Lcd_Init();
             lcd_cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
             lcd_out(1,1,"PENYIRAM TANAMAN");
             lcd_out(2,5,"OTOMATIS");
             delay_ms(1500);
             Lcd_cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
             lcd_cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
             lcd_out(1,3,"DENGAN CINTA");
             lcd_out(2,4,"KELOMPOK 2");
             delay_ms(1500);
             Lcd_cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
             lcd_cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
             lcd_out(1,3,"MENGHITUNG");
             lcd_out(2,2,"KEKERINGAN...");
             delay_ms(1500);
             lcd_cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
             lcd_out(1,4,"KEKERINGAN:");

while(1){
         if(cset==0){
                     cset=1;
//calculate R
                     SetMoistR= SetMoist % 10;
                     switch (SetMoistR) {
                                          case 0: SetMoistR=0x3F; break;
                                          case 1: SetMoistR=0x06; break;
                                          case 2: SetMoistR=0x5B; break;
                                          case 3: SetmoistR=0x4F; break;
                                          case 4: SetmoistR=0x66; break;
                                          case 5: SetmoistR=0x6D; break;
                                          case 6: SetmoistR=0x7D; break;
                                          case 7: SetmoistR=0x07; break;
                                          case 8: SetmoistR=0x7F; break;
                                          case 9: SetmoistR=0x6F; break;
                                          }
// end of R calculation

//calculate L
                       SetMoistL= (SetMoist/10) % 10;
                       switch (SetMoistL) {
                                          case 0: SetMoistL=0x3F; break;
                                          case 1: SetMoistL=0x06; break;
                                          case 2: SetMoistL=0x5B; break;
                                          case 3: SetmoistL=0x4F; break;
                                          case 4: SetmoistL=0x66; break;
                                          case 5: SetmoistL=0x6D; break;
                                          case 6: SetmoistL=0x7D; break;
                                          case 7: SetmoistL=0x07; break;
                                          case 8: SetmoistL=0x7F; break;
                                          case 9: SetmoistL=0x6F; break;
                                          }
//end of L calculation
                      }
//7Segment
          portd=SetmoistR;
          portc.b7=0;
          portd.b7=1;
          delay_ms(100);
          portd=SetmoistL;
          portd.b7=0;
          portc.b7=1;
          delay_ms(50);
//End_7Segment

//IntToStr(getMoist,buffer);
           buffer[0] = (getMoist/10)%10 +48;
           buffer[1] = (getMoist)%10+48;
           lcd_chr(2,8,buffer[0]);
           lcd_chr(2,9,buffer[1]);
           lcd_chr(2,11,'%');

           if(turnON==1){
                         LCD_ON;
                         }
           else{
                LCD_OFF;
                }

        } //while


     }       //main
```

Comment: If you want any help you had to show your code. But the answer is `NO`, the external interrupt just jumps to address 0x04 in your PIC. Not more and not less.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- I think your problem is not the code, but the hardware. Unfortunately this site is about software, so please consider to move over to [electronics.se] and to show the schematic. Specifically switching inductive loads like relays or motors needs to be done correctly.

Comment: @Mike I have posted my code

Comment: You had to reset the interrupt flag in your ISR, otherwise the IST is called again and again. And please indent your code, it's really hard to read.

Comment: @Mike which line should I reset the external interrupt

Comment: Reset the interruptflag in your ISR.

Comment: `if(getMoist>setMoist){
                                                                                    portc.b0=0b1;
                                                                                    if (PORTC.b0=0b1){
                                                                                    INTCON.b0=0;`
how about this? @Mike